# What's a good, wholesome, smut-free site where I can 'publish' my fiction writings for my friends to read?

Tags: fiction, publishing, self-publishing

I (we) just cannot seem to find one. I promised my real-life friends (located all across the country) that I'd write up our RPG campaign as I have other fictional subjects and put it online it so they can read it, share it, etc. Some long-time internet friends from unsuitable websites want to follow me there as well, and I'd like to gain more in the same manner if I can.

However every site I go to either starts out fanfic (as I did) or becomes that in fairly short order. My friends are not underage, but they are definitely not into any of that at all! If the site I choose is more than, like, 30% fan-fiction and/or smut I will never hear the end of it. ^_^

I freaking *love* doing this, and I'm told I'm quite good at it - if that matters. If anyone out there has a partial idea of where to go but you're not sure I'd fit in or qualify, you have only to ask for the details; please do! I've already written and re-re-re-reread the first chapter (I am finicky) and it is EPIC, imho. What do I do with it?

Comment: Does it need to be a site that is already oriented around publishing fiction, or would publishing on a blog or journal site (where people subscribe to *your* content, independently of what else is hosted there) meet your need?

Comment: Isn't this off topic because it's both opinion based and a list question?

Comment: @abagfullofcats Create your own website. Nothing there but your own content. Use one of the free blogging platforms (Wordpress.com, Blogger) or any hosting provider.

Comment: Why does it matter if there is smut elsewhere on the site if your readers are only going to read your writing? It's not like your paladin is going to catch the Johnlock Virus and suddenly start smooching the cleric because your RPG story happens to share a top-level URL with some slashfic.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at [FictionPress](https://www.fictionpress.com/). It has rules against how 'smutty' something can be so things aren't supposed to get too steamy, and it redirects any fan-fiction to the sister site [FanFiction.net](https://www.fanfiction.net/) keeping FictionPress (mostly) fan-fiction free.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Wattpad? It does have a lot of fanfic and some smut, but the volume of other offerings are much greater and both you and your friends could avoid those if you chose.